# open Date Picker Dialog of prevoius days from today for selecting date of birth

Tags: android

I want to open date picker dialog showing previous date from today.  As I have to select Date of birth.
That is will not show coming days,month and year.

Is this possible in android?

Comment: Everything is possible. you just need to try..!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            dp.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-(24*60*60*1000));
            return dp;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        }
    }
```

Showing the date picker:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

For more information visit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

Answer (score 0):

Tricks:

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);//show previous date from today 
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                            int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        tv.setText(formatDate(calendar.getTime()));
                    }
                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.show();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```